# Trouble with achieving convergence in nonlinear mixed-effects model in Pinhiero and Bates book

Tags: r, nlme

I am working through Pinhiero and Bates' book *Mixed Effects Models in S and S-Plus* in R. I am having trouble getting a model in Chapter 8 (p. 387) to converge.

```
library(nlme)

fm1Wafer.nlmeR <- nlme(current ~ A + B * cos(4.5679 * voltage) + C * sin(4.5679 * voltage),
                       data = Wafer,
                       fixed = list(A ~ voltage + I(voltage^2), B + C ~ 1),
                       random = list(Wafer = A ~ voltage + I(voltage^2),
                                     Site = pdBlocked(list(A ~ 1, A ~ voltage + I(voltage^2)-1))),
                       start = c(-4.26, 5.62, 1.26, -0.10, 0.10), # starting values taken from fixed effects of another model earlier in the book
                       method = "REML",
                       control = nlmeControl(opt = "nlm"))
```

As you can see I have tried the `nlm` optimizer. The default `nlminb` optimiser does not work either. Both yield this error message

```
Error in nlme.formula(current ~ A + B * cos(4.5679 * voltage) + C * sin(4.5679 *  : 
  maximum number of iterations (maxIter = 50) reached without convergence
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In logLik.reStruct(object, conLin) :
  Singular precision matrix in level -2, block 1
2: In logLik.reStruct(object, conLin) :
  Singular precision matrix in level -2, block 1
```

Any suggestions? There are several models based on this one downstream in the book so it would be nice to get it to converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error would suggest that setting something like `nlmeControl(opt = "nlm", maxIter = 2000)` would help, but actually it didn't. I tried 4000 but it was taking forever...

What appears to be the real culprit is `method = "REML"`. Leaving the default `"ML"` gives the expected result.

```
fm1Wafer.nlmeR <- nlme(current ~ A + B * cos(4.5679 * voltage) + C * sin(4.5679 * voltage),
                       data = Wafer,
                       fixed = list(A ~ voltage + I(voltage^2), B + C ~ 1),
                       random = list(Wafer = A ~ voltage + I(voltage^2),
                                     Site = pdBlocked(list(A ~ 1, A ~ voltage + I(voltage^2) - 1))),
                       start = c(-4.26, 5.62, 1.26, -0.10, 0.10))
```

Comment: Thank you @Julius Vainora. Yes i tried more iterations with the same result. Will depart from the book and switch it back to full ML.