# Trouble with Convergence in Non-Linear Mixed-Effects Model from Pinheiro and Bates

Tags: r, nlme

My ongoing problems (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927436/model-failure-for-nonlinear-mixed-effects-model-from-pinhiero-and-bates/53930843#53930843) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53926442/trouble-with-achieving-convergence-in-nonlinear-mixed-effects-model-in-pinhiero/53926628#53926628)) making the nonlinear mixed effects models in Chapter 8 of Pinheiro and Bates converge continue. This time with the `Quinidine` dataset (p. 385). Once again this is an iterative model-building exercise. I am having trouble with the third model in the series.

```
library(nlme)
fm1Quin.nlme <- nlme(conc ~ quinModel(Subject, time, conc, dose, interval, lV, lKa, lCl),
                     data = Quinidine, 
                     fixed = lV + lKa + lCl ~ 1,
                     random = pdDiag(lV + lCl ~ 1),
                     groups = ~ Subject,
                     start = list(fixed = c(5, -0.3, 2)),
                     na.action = na.pass, # R does not have the function na.include
                     naPattern = ~ !is.na(conc))
fm1Quin.fix <- fixef(fm1Quin.nlme)
fm2Quin.nlme <- update(fm1Quin.nlme, 
                       fixed = list(lCl ~ glyco, lKa + lV ~ 1),
                       start = c(fm1Quin.fix[3], 0, fm1Quin.fix[2:1]))
fm2Quin.fix <- fixef(fm2Quin.nlme)
```

Now for the troublesome model

```
fm3Quin.nlme <- update(fm2Quin.nlme,
                       fixed = list(lCl ~ glyco + Creatinine, lKa + lV ~ 1),
                       start = c(fm2Quin.fix[1:2], 0.2, fm2Quin.fix[3:4]),
                       control = nlmeControl(maxIter = 50))
```

I tried setting the maximum number of iterations higher in `nlmeControl` but keep getting similar error messages

```
Error in nlme.formula(model = conc ~ quinModel(Subject, time, conc, dose,  : 
  maximum number of iterations (maxIter = 50) reached without convergence
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In nlme.formula(model = conc ~ quinModel(Subject, time, conc, dose,  :
  Singular precision matrix in level -1, block 1
2: In nlme.formula(model = conc ~ quinModel(Subject, time, conc, dose,  :
  Singular precision matrix in level -1, block 1
3: In nlme.formula(model = conc ~ quinModel(Subject, time, conc, dose,  :
  Singular precision matrix in level -1, block 1
4: In nlme.formula(model = conc ~ quinModel(Subject, time, conc, dose,  :
  Singular precision matrix in level -1, block 1
5: In nlme.formula(model = conc ~ quinModel(Subject, time, conc, dose,  :
  Singular precision matrix in level -1, block 1
6: In nlme.formula(model = conc ~ quinModel(Subject, time, conc, dose,  :
  Singular precision matrix in level -1, block 1
7: In nlme.formula(model = conc ~ quinModel(Subject, time, conc, dose,  :
  Singular precision matrix in level -1, block 1
```

It seems as if there is more finesse required in getting these nonlinear models to converge in R than with the linear mixed-effects models. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `fm1Quin.fix` is currently undefined.

Comment: Sorry @Julius Vainora, I have added this. It still fails to converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This time we may achieve convergence with the help of two things: different initial values and a different value for `pnlsTol`:

```
fm3Quin.nlme <- update(fm2Quin.nlme,
                       fixed = list(lCl ~ glyco + Creatinine, lKa + lV ~ 1),
                       start = c(3.0291, -0.3631, 0.1503, -0.7458, 5.2893),
                       control = nlmeControl(pnlsTol = 0.0011))
```

Note that the default value of `pnlsTol` is 0.001, so the change is really tiny. The starting values are actually the ones provided in the book as the optimal solution, so it's kind of cheating. However, `fm3Quin.nlme` converges to a slightly different values... In this case my guess would be that the function is very nonlinear and the achieved optimum is very close to other much larger values, hence the complicated convergence. (I'm guessing this because of the need to increase `pnlsTol` and to specify good initial values.)